# crawler4j compile error with class CrawlConfig - VariableDeclaratorId Expected

Tags: crawler4j

The code will not compile. I changed the JRE to 1.7. The compiler does not highlight the class in Eclipse and the CrawlConfig appears to fail in the compiler. The class should be run from the command line in Linux.

Any ideas?

Compiler Error -
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "crawlStorageFolder", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token  zeocrawler.java /zeowebcrawler/src/main/java/com/example    line 95 Java Problem

```
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.fetcher.PageFetcher;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.parser.HtmlParseData;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtServer;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;

    public class Controller {   

         String crawlStorageFolder = "/data/crawl/root";
        int numberOfCrawlers = 7;

        CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();

        config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

        PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
        RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
        RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
        CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

           controller.addSeed("http://www.senym.com");
            controller.addSeed("http://www.merrows.co.uk");
            controller.addSeed("http://www.zeoic.com");


            controller.start(MyCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);








    }
    public URLConnection connectURL(String strURL) {
        URLConnection conn =null;
        try {
        URL inputURL = new URL(strURL);
        conn = inputURL.openConnection();
            int test = 0;

        }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid URL");
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to the URL");
        }
        return conn;
        }

    public static void updatelongurl()
    {

//      System.out.println("Short URL: "+ shortURL);
//        urlConn =  connectURL(shortURL);
 //       urlConn.getHeaderFields();
 //       System.out.println("Original URL: "+ urlConn.getURL());

/* connectURL - This function will take a valid url and return a 
URL object representing the url address. */



    }






    public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

        private      Pattern FILTERS = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g" 
                                                          + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4"
                                                          + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf" 
                                                          + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

        /**
         * You should implement this function to specify whether
         * the given url should be crawled or not (based on your
         * crawling logic).
         */
        @Override
        public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
                String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
                return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");
        }

        /**
         * This function is called when a page is fetched and ready 
         * to be processed by your program.
         */
        @Override
        public void visit(Page page) {          
                String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
                System.out.println("URL: " + url);

                if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
                        HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
                        String text = htmlParseData.getText();
                        String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
                        List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();

                        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
                        System.out.println("Html length: " + html.length());
                        System.out.println("Number of outgoing links: " + links.size());
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty strange error since the code seems to be clean. Try to start eclipse with the -clean option on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`String crawlStorageFolder = "/data/crawl/root";`

to

`String crawlStorageFolder = "./data/crawl/root";`

i.e. add a leading `.`